# ASP.NET MVC results are not being filtered out

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a page index.cshtml and in that i call another page test.cshtml using iframes. The page test.cshtml contains code to filter out some stuff. Even though the values are being filtered out when it comes to UI it is not showing the filtered values. Can you please help me in identifying what i am missing.

Below is the sample code

index.cshtml

```
<div class="wrapper">
        <div class="h_iframe">
            <img class="ratio" src="/images/ratio16x9.png" />
                <iframe src="@Url.Action("test","Home")" frameborder="0"></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
```

test.cshtml

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="onpageloadvalues">

 @foreach (var catgoryabstractslists in ViewBag.abstracts)
        {
            <div><a href="#" data-id='@catgoryabstractslists.AbstractID' id='CategorySelect_@(catgoryabstractslists.AbstractID)' class="select-abstracts">Abstract #@catgoryabstractslists.AbstractID - @catgoryabstractslists.AbstractTitle</a></div>
           }

</div>

</div>

$('.select-abstracts').click(function () {
        var data = $(this).attr('data-id');
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("GetAllAbstracts", "Home")',
            data: { abstractid: data },
            success: function (result) {
            },
            error: function () {
                alert('Error');
            }
        });
    });
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult GetAllAbstracts(string categoryname)
        {
            List<Abstracts> abstracts = Helpers.SchedOrgHelpers.LoadAbstracts();            
            abstracts = abstracts.Where(x => x.Category == categoryname).ToList();

            //Populate the Viewbag using the helpers method            
            ViewBag.abstracts = abstracts;

            return View("....");
        }
```

Comment: Have you set your debugger on the foreach? Why does the GetAllAbstracts return a View? This is MVC - not ASPX. The page has no state - it's just plain simple html

Comment: Show us your controller actions btw.

Answer (score 2):

You are making the call to server via ajax and inside that you are setting the filtered data to ViewBag, but you are not reading that again from server (your page is not executed at server again becacuse your call is via ajax).

What you should be doing is, instead of setting it to ViewBag, you should either send it as JSON data (and in your ajax success method, parse the json array and build the html markup and append/replace the specific DOM element) or a return partial view which uses this data to render whatever markup you need and replace the existing DOM element you want.

Comment: Passing a model to a partial view will also help keep your view strongly typed to prevent other errors. Always pass a model to a view instead of using ViewBag.